# How do I display a placeholder element at current insertion point during drag and drop operation?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list that I can sort with drag and drop using react, and it works fine. The way it works is onDragEnter, the items get replaced. What I want to do though, is show a placeholder element once the dragging item is hovering over available space. So the final placement would happen in onDragEnd. I have two functions that handle dragging:

```
  const handleDragStart = (index) => {
    draggingItem.current = index;
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (index) => {
    if (draggingWidget.current !== null) return;

    dragOverItem.current = index;

    const listCopy = [...rows];
    const draggingItemContent = listCopy[draggingItem.current];

    listCopy.splice(draggingItem.current, 1);
    listCopy.splice(dragOverItem.current, 0, draggingItemContent);

    if (draggingItem.current === currentRowIndex) {
      setCurrentRowIndex(dragOverItem.current);
    }

    draggingItem.current = dragOverItem.current;
    dragOverItem.current = null;

    setRows(listCopy);
  };
```

and in react jsx template, I have this:

```
      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          draggable
          onDragStart={() => handleDragStart(index)}
          onDragEnter={() => handleDragEnter(index)}
          onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
          onDragEnd={handleDragEndRow}
        >
...
</div>
```

Can anyone come with any tips as to how I might solve this?

Answer (score 2):

To display a placeholder indicating where you are about to drop the dragged item,  you need to compute the insertion point according to the current drag position.

So dragEnter won't do, dargOver is best suited to do that.

When dragging over the first half of the dragged overItem, the placeholder insertion point will be before the dragged over item, when dragging over the second half, it will be after. (see getBouldingClientRect, height/2 usages, of course if dragging horizontally width will need to be accounted for).

The actual insertion point (in the data, not the UI), if drag succeeds, will depend on if we're dropping before or after the initial position.

The following snippet demonstrate a way of doing that with the following changes in your initial code:

- Avoided numerous refs vars by putting everything in state, especially because changing these will have an effect on the UI (will need rerender)
- Avoided separate useState calls by putting all vars in a common state variable and a common setState modifier
- Avoided unnecessary modifications of the rows state var, rows should change only when drag ends as it's easier to reason about it => the placeholder is not actually part of the data, it serves purpose only in the ui
- Avoided defining handler in the render code `onEvent={() => handler(someVar)}` by using dataset key `data-drag-index`, the index can retrieved after using this key: `const index = element.dataset.dragIndex`. The handler can live with the event only which is automatically passed.
- Avoided recreating (from the children props point of view) these handlers at each render by using React.useCallback.

The various css class added show the current state of each item but serves no functionnal purpose.

StateDisplay component also serves no purpose besides showing what happens to understand this answer.

**Edit:** Reworked and fixed fully working solution handling all tested edge cases

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state,setState] = React.useState({
    rows: [
      {name: 'foo'},
      {name: 'bar'},
      {name: 'baz'},
      {name: 'kazoo'}
    ],
    draggedIndex: -1,
    overIndex: -1,
    overZone: null,
    placeholderIndex: -1
  });
  const { rows, draggedIndex, overIndex, overZone, placeholderIndex } = state;
  const handleDragStart = React.useCallback((evt) => {
    const index = indexFromEvent(evt);
    setState(s => ({ ...s, draggedIndex: index }));
  });

  const handleDragOver = React.useCallback((evt) => {
  var rect = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = evt.clientX - rect.left; // x position within the element.
      var y = evt.clientY - rect.top;  // y position within the element.
    // dataset variables are strings
    const newOverIndex = indexFromEvent(evt);
    const newOverZone = y <= rect.height / 2 ? 'top' : 'bottom';
    
    const newState = { ...state, overIndex: newOverIndex, overZone: newOverZone }
    let newPlaceholderIndex = placeholderIndexFromState(newOverIndex, newOverZone);
    // if placeholder is just before (==draggedIndex) or just after (===draggedindex + 1) there is not need to show it because we're not moving anything
    if (newPlaceholderIndex === draggedIndex || newPlaceholderIndex === draggedIndex + 1) {
        newPlaceholderIndex = -1;
    }
    const nonFonctionalConditionOnlyForDisplay = overIndex !== newOverIndex || overZone !== newOverZone;
    // only update if placeholderIndex hasChanged
    if (placeholderIndex !== newPlaceholderIndex || nonFonctionalConditionOnlyForDisplay) {
      newState.placeholderIndex = newPlaceholderIndex;
      setState(s => ({ ...s, ...newState }));
    }
  });
  const handleDragEnd = React.useCallback((evt) => {
    const index = indexFromEvent(evt);
    // we know that much: no more dragged item, no more placeholder
    const updater = { draggedIndex: -1, placeholderIndex: -1,overIndex: -1, overZone: null };
    if (placeholderIndex !== -1) {
      // from here rows need to be updated
      // copy rows
      updater.rows = [...rows];
      // mutate updater.rows, move item at dragged index to placeholderIndex
      if (placeholderIndex > index) {
      // inserting after so removing the elem first and shift insertion index by -1
        updater.rows.splice(index, 1);
        updater.rows.splice(placeholderIndex - 1, 0, rows[index]);
      } else {
        // inserting before, so do not shift
        updater.rows.splice(index, 1);
        updater.rows.splice(placeholderIndex, 0, rows[index]);
      }
    }
    setState(s => ({
      ...s,
      ...updater
    }));
  });
  

  const renderedRows = rows.map((row, index) =>  (
    <div
      key={row.name}
      data-drag-index={index}
      className={
        `row ${
          index === draggedIndex
            ? 'dragged-row'
            : 'normal-row'}`
      }
      draggable
      onDragStart={handleDragStart}
      onDragOver={handleDragOver}
      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
    >
      {row.name}
    </div>
  ));
  // there is a placeholder to show, add it to the rendered rows
  if (placeholderIndex !== -1) {
    renderedRows.splice(
      placeholderIndex,
      0,
      <Placeholder />
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {renderedRows}
      <StateDisplay state={state} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Placeholder = ({ index }) => (
    <div
      key="placeholder"
      className="row placeholder-row"
    ></div>
  );
function indexFromEvent(evt) {
    try {
        return parseInt(evt.target.dataset.dragIndex, 10);
    } catch (err) {
       return -1;
    }
}
function placeholderIndexFromState(overIndex, overZone) {
    if (overZone === null) {
      return;
    }
    if (overZone === 'top') {
      return overIndex;
    } else {
      return overIndex + 1;
    }
}
const StateDisplay = ({ state }) => {
  return (
    <div className="state-display">
      {state.rows.map(r => r.name).join()}<br />
      draggedIndex: {state.draggedIndex}<br />
      overIndex: {state.overIndex}<br />
      overZone: {state.overZone}<br />
      placeholderIndex: {state.placeholderIndex}<br />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.row { width: 100px; height: 30px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
.row:nth-child(n+1) {  margin-top: 5px; }
.row.normal-row { background: #BEBEBE; }
.row.placeholder-row { background: #BEBEFE; }
.row.normal-row:hover { background: #B0B0B0; }
.row.placeholder-row:hover { background: #B0B0F0; }

.row.dragged-row { opacity: 0.3; background: #B0B0B0; }
.row.dragged-row:hover { background: #B0B0B0; }

.state-display { position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; }
```

```html
<html><body><div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></body></html>
```